# 実践 and 実戦 in exercises

Tags: word-choice, words, kanji-choice

I've seen both 実践 and 実戦 used in the context of practice questions, both pronounced じっせん, of course.

実践問題 seems to be the more common of the two, meaning a practice exercise, but I've recently come across one which instead says 実戦問題.

Firstly, I'd like to confirm this isn't a typo, given that 実戦 refers to combat. If the text is correct, and both 実戦問題 and 実践問題 are technically accepted, Is there a difference in meaning or nuance between the two?

Answer (score 2):

In Japan, entrance exams (usually of college; sometimes of high school and middle school) are often compared to battle or war. For example, the slogan of 代々木{よよぎ}ゼミナール, one of the largest entrance exam prep school, is 日々是決戦{ひびこれけっせん} (decisive battle every day). So 実戦問題 is a kind of pun and means super-practical, must-learn problems.